# Error building Swift Cocoa Touch Framework after adding Swift file: <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a problem creating a Swift Cocoa Touch Framework. As soon as I add my first .swift file, clean, then build I get a build error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'MyTextFramework'
```

This is easily reproducible from scratch in just a few steps using Xcode 6.1.1

- Create new Cocoa Touch Framework using Swift Language
- Add an iOS swift file
- Build - ***OK***
- Clean - ***OK***
- Build - ***ERROR***
- From here on the project will not build unless I delete the swift file.

I've tried the typical Xcode magic such as deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, etc.

---

**Steps detailed below with screenshots:**

File > New > Project > iOS Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework
[image]

Product Name: MyTextFramework

Language: Swift
[image]

I now have a bare bones Cocoa Touch Framework.
[image]

Add an iOS Swift file named FooBaz.swift

Add a class that extends NSObject and an init function.

***The target still builds fine at this point.***
[image]

Cmd-K to clean the project

Cmd-B to build again... ***BAM***
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to use this Swift framework from Objective-C, the easiest solution is to get rid of MyTextFramework.h

Comment: This is correct and does solve the question I asked. I'd like to know why it has to be removed, and what happens if I did want to use my framework in Obj-C and not just Swift?

Comment: Did you figure this out ever?  This is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

As Georg Tuparev answered, I just need to remove MyTextFramework.h and it builds fine. However, this prevents using my framework in Obj-C code.

Is it even possible to build a framework containing Swift code that can be used in both Swift AND Obj-C? If it is technically possible, then it seems this issue with Xcode would prevent anyone from actually doing it. Does anyone have any comments or solutions for this scenario?